# log in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, logging

In my mvc application i need to check a condition in action and throw it to the log.

How can i add a info to log info.

Answer (score 3):

To use the event log:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry()
```

Or look at a library like [log4net](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/) or [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **EMAB** or **Log4Net** libraries?

Yes...there are built-in classes but instead of building it ground-up the best method is to use established frameworks.

Check this out >>> [MS Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139916.aspx)
And if your needs are at a very basic level the [System.IO.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733028.aspx) should suffice.

For unhandled errors **ELMAH** is the easiest to use.

Comment: can't we do this with any build in classes